# How to detect Brazilian portuguese as device language in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity, I'm trying to detect the OS language used by the device so I can display my texts in the same language. I'm currently using the `Application.systemLanguage` but I have troubles with Brazilian Portuguese as it isn't listed in the `SystemLanguage enum`, only Portuguese. Is there another way to detect this language ?

Comment: There are other people asking for in in the net, so probably with this tool you will not get it. The only solution I see is to write plugin for each device to fetch the system language.

Comment: Also you could check device time and see if it is more in Portugal or Brasil time. Of course this solution is very weak ;)

Comment: Yeah, I saw some people with the same problem but never an answer. I thought that here at least I would have one even if it's "you can't" :p.

Comment: LOL that's a creative solution indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find this plugin helpful: http://u3d.as/vXf
You can read user's region using it and differentiate between Portuguese and Brazilian Portuguese